# How to add message type as object in ProtoBuf (gRPC) - Proto3 Syntax?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3, protobuf.js, grpc-node

How to send message type as object in ProtoBuf - Proto3 Syntax?

I want to transfer object instead of string or number.

#### Example

```
{
  name: 'One',
  date: 'date',
  some: 'some',
...
...
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

package db;

service Proxy
{
    rpc myFunction(Request) returns (Response);
}

message Request
{
    string name = 1;
}

message Response
{
    object keyvalue = 1;
}
```

Here, I am getting error

```
throw Error("no such Type or Enum '" + path + "' in " + this);
        ^

Error: no such Type or Enum 'object' in Type
```

--

#### Workaround

I can convert it to string in server side, and then I can JSON.parse() at client.

But I want to know, if there any better way to do it.

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is here? What kind of object are you trying to represent?

Comment: Added more description with example, can you please look into it?

Answer (score 9):

> [protocol-buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) does not support the object data type!

But you can emulate your data as hierarchically by using **protocol buffer message type** itself.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package db;

service Proxy
{
    rpc myFunction(Request) returns (Response);
}

message Request
{
    string name = 1;
}

message Response
{
    message obj {
         string key1 = 1;
         string key2 = 2
    }
    obj keyvalue = 1;   // Here you have created your own type obj.
}
```

In the above example, you can see that the Response message now has "**keyvalue**" field of type ***obj***(which is a custom type you have just built).

Now you will pass Object in a callback from the server instead of primitive type.

```
callback(null, { keyvalue: { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" } });
```

---

> Let's say if keys are unknown to you but key/value pair data type is same and known to you then, in this case, you can use
>   `map<type, type>`

```
message Response
{
   map<string, string> keyvalue = 1;
}
callback(null, { keyvalue: { "key1": "value1", "key5": "value2" } });
```

References:-

- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Struct

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you can likely use one of three types.

1. The `bytes` type represents an arbitrary string of bytes. You can choose to encode your types in anyway you feel appropriate.
2. The `any` type represents an arbitrary protobuf message, allowing the client or server to encode non-predefined messages. This is a string of bytes, with a unique identifier per message type and language implementations will have ways to unpack the message.
3. You mention using Javascript. You could likely define a Javascript object message using a combination of `oneof` for the basic types and `map` for object types.

Answer (score 2):

If all of the keys and values you want to send have the same type, you can use a map type. Your example shows string keys and string values, so that could use the type `map<string, string>`.

If you want to send arbitrary object data with similar structure to JSON objects, you can use the [`google.protobuf.Struct`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Struct) message type.